# FlurlHttp not including response in event handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, flurl

I am trying to get some information from my response when handling errors, but I cannot seem to figure out why the response is never included. I have tried both `AfterCall` and `OnError`, both do not contain the response.

Request code:

```cs
    return await ResponseDeserializer.DeserializeResponse<Account>(
                await userAccount.GetStreamAsync(HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, ct),
                "value",
                ct);
```

As you can see, I have specified `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead` which, as far as I understand, means Flurl considers a request as "complete" only when it has read the response its content.

My current builder code for configuring requests:

```cs
        request.BeforeCall(call => { call.LogStartCall(); });

        request.OnError(call =>
        {
            call.LogIfFailed();
        });

        request.AfterCall(call =>
        {
            if (expectSystemMessage)
            {
                call.TryFindSystemMessage();
            }
        });

        return request;
```

And finally, a short snippet of the code for `LogIfFailed()`:

```cs
        Url requestUrl = call.Request.Url;

        var options = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "json", call.RequestBody },
            { "query", call.Request.Url.Query },
            { "headers", string.Join(" , ", call.Request.Headers.Where(tuple => !tuple.Name.Equals("Authorization"))) },
        };

        LogContext.PushProperty("method", call.Request.Verb.Method);
        LogContext.PushProperty("base_uri", call.Request.Url.Root);
        LogContext.PushProperty("uri", call.Request.Url.Path);
        LogContext.PushProperty("options", options);

        if (call.Response is null)
        {
            Log.Error("API request failed");
            return;
        }

        LogContext.PushProperty("duration", call.Duration.Value.Milliseconds.ToString());
        LogContext.PushProperty("response", await call.Response.GetStringAsync());
        LogContext.PushProperty("status_code", call.Response.StatusCode.ToString());

        if (!call.Response.Headers.TryGetFirst("SysMessages", out string? message))
        {
            Log.Error("API request failed");
            return;
        }
```

I read `AfterCall` and `OnError` can handle both synchronous as well as asynchronous methods, and `LogIfFailed()` is an asynchronous method.

If it helps, I am on FlurlHttp version 3.2.2!

How can I get Flurl to always include a response when available?

Thanks in advance!